# Is there an easy way to have the summary fields for deductible contributions be based on calendar year?

Tags: contributions, summaryfields

I went to generate letters to our contributors telling them how much they donated in 2015 that was deductible for their taxes.  I discovered that total deductible contributions for last year is based upon our FY which is Jul - Jun.

Clearly, that number is worthless to most individuals since most people base their taxes on calendar year.

So is there an easy way to get it to be based upon CY?

As I write this and think about it, I guess the best answer would be to include another summary field for just that or maybe for this year, last year and year before.  Most of year we really don't care about contributions by CY, just for the tax reporting thing.

There are, of course, a couple of other ways, tokens for example, to get the number.  The nice thing about the summary fields is the ability to use them in searches so we can say only get the people who donated more than a certain amount and to only get people who made tax deductible donations.  (Too bad the search form doesn't have a deductible checkbox.  One has to wade through all their financial types and pick the ones that are.)

Comment: I think I do this using the entity messages extension - but summary fields might be easier. I use entity messages to generate a table of 'selected' contributions from a search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is now available either in Summary Fields itself or via https://civicrm.org/extensions/joinerys-more-summary-fields

Comment: Looks like the more summary fields supports this.  Yea.  Any idea if this one works in 4.6?  I suppose I could just try it on a test db.

Comment: No idea - we moved all our sites of 4.6 a long time back

Answer (score 0):

Check out our CDN TaxReceipts Extension - 
https://civicrm.org/extensions/cdn-tax-receipts

It has been written in conjunction with a Canadian BDO Tax Partner but the extension is used is other countries as well - some of its features include:

- single, aggregate and annual Tax Receipt/letter
- bulk receipting
- email, print and data issuing methods
- email tracked openings feature (know if your donors opened their PDF Tax Receipt/letter)
- handles is-deductible (at Financial type level)
- handles lineItems (some may be is-deductible; some may not)
- handles non-deductible amount field
- has hooks for developers such as: calculate additional non-deductible $ amount (for example to handle event expenses per ticket purchased)
- has a PDF template feature (used FPDI - print a stack of Tax receipts/letters your own template)
- has solid reports for audit - tracks re-receipting (issuing duplicates)
- and more!